# how i can fill the grid when it is in DataControlDetailDescriptor in devexpress in wpf

Tags: wpf, windows, devexpress

How i can fill grid when it is inside  DataControlDetailDescriptor in devexpress in wpf

and what is  itemsSourcePathand which value should i assign to this  ItemsSourcePath.
dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourcePath="AccessProfiles".

```
  <dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"         Margin="-9,52,0,0" Name="gridControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="415" Width="623" MasterRowExpanding="gridControl1_MasterRowExpanding" AutoExpandAllGroups="True" >
        <!--ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bindd, Mode=OneWay}"-->

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" ShowTotalSummary="True" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
            <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor     x:Name="detail1" ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding Path=Bindd, Converter={StaticResource AlternationConverter1}}">
                <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                    <dxg:GridControl Name="detailGrid" AutoPopulateColumns="True" >

                        <dxg:GridControl.View >

                            <dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Row" ShowGroupPanel="False"  ShowTotalSummary="True" />
                        </dxg:GridControl.View>
                    </dxg:GridControl>
                </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
            </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
        </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check the [DataControlDetailDescriptor class documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/clsDevExpressXpfGridDataControlDetailDescriptortopic) at first.
The [DataControlDetailDescriptor.ItemsSourcePath property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlDetailDescriptor_ItemsSourcePathtopic) is also completely described with it's help-reference.
Related example: [Create details with a grid and custom content and put them in a tabbed container](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4031)